# Typo3 - get Headerlink in Navigation

Tags: typo3, typoscript

i have an Menu, in this Menu i get the Data from a Col (colPos50) that work fine. But i also need the Headerlink from this page but it doesn't work.

```
50 = COA
            50 {
              ###########
              20 = CONTENT
              20 {
              table = tt_content
              select {
                pidInList.data = register:meinRegister
                where = colPos=50
                }
                wrap = <div id="c{field:uid}">|<a href="{field:header_link}" class="button orange left">Zum Vertrieb</a></div>
                wrap.insertData = 1
              }
              ###########
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stdWrap.typolink {
    wrap = <div class="linkwrap">|</div>
    parameter.insertData = 1
    parameter = {field:header_link}
    ATagParams = class="headerLink"
    ATagBeforeWrap = 1
}
```